# Elixir printing a list confusion

Tags: elixir

I wrote a simple program like this. I see strange behavior

```
  listks = [8,9,10]
  IO.inspect(listks, label: "My Label")
```

When I run the above program, the display output is `'\b\t\n\v'`.

If I run the same program with lists as `[1, 2, 3]` the display output is correct.

Guide me

Sincerley,
Arvind